# Automorphisms of $GL_n(K)$, and $SL_n(K)$

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, automorphism-group

There are (at least) two types of "trivial" automorphisms of $GL_n(K)$: the inner automorphisms, and the automorphisms arising as extensions of automorphisms of $K$.("trivial" in that they can be thought of for any field $K$)

However, both of these types of automorphism fix $SL_n(K)$.  I was looking for examples of a field $K$ and an automorphism of $GL_n(K)$ that doesn't fix $SL_n(K)$.

Are there any ? Are there some for any field $K\neq \mathbb{F}_2$ (obviously this field doesn't have any since $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_2) = SL_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$) ? If not, for which fields can there exist some ? Are there nice and easy examples ?

Comment: Every automorphism of $GL_n(k)$ must preserve the determinant, and so maps $SL_n(k)$ to itself.

Comment: Why must an automorphism preserve the determinant ?

Comment: @Joppy Complex conjugation induces an automorphism of $ GL_n(\mathbb C) $ which does not preserve the determinant. (It still fixes $ SL $, however.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, the derived subgroup of $ GL_n(K) $ is $ SL_n(K) $ as long as $ |K| \geq 3 $ or $ n \geq 3 $. If $ |K| = 2 $, the claim is trivially true; and if $ |K| \geq 3 $, this result implies that any automorphism fixes $ SL_n(K) $ as automorphisms map commutators to commutators.

Comment: Yes obviously; why didn't I think of that ? Thanks a lot !